# Adding 7x7 grid based tabla-data tags to table via Javascript (Battleships game)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple battleship game with Javascript. The game should feature a 7x7 grid system and the battleships should be placed randomly on the grid, both vertically and horizontally.

Here's the code creating the 1x7 grid (horizontally):

```
/* Declare length of battleground */
var battleground = 7;

/* Calculate and position the battleships */
while (battleground < 7);
var battlegroundCalc = parseInt(battleground) - 2;
var randomLoc = Math.floor(Math.random() * battlegroundCalc);
var location1 = randomLoc;
var location2 = location1 + 1;
var location3 = location2 + 1;
console.log(location1);
console.log(location2);
console.log(location3);

/* Add tiles to construct the battleground */
for (var i = 0; i < battleground; i++){
    document.getElementById('tableRow').innerHTML +="<td id='"+i+"'></td>"
};
```

However I am having difficulties in figuring out how to create multiple rows, so I get a 7x7 grid.

If anybody could help me out with that, I would be really grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Repeat the same process for each row. From what I can recall of battleships, ships can be placed horizontally and vertically.  You will need to allow for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
var dimensionx = 7;
var grid = new Array(dimensionx);

var i, j, row, box;

// this is our table
var board = document.getElementById('tbody_id');

for (i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    grid[i] = new Array(dimensionx);
    grid[i].fill('~'); //fill the grid with water
    row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
        box = document.createElement('td');
        box.setAttribute('id', "" + i + j); //practical identification for cells
        row.appendChild(box);
    }
    board.appendChild(row);
}
```

The difference here is that I create a 2-dimensional array before I start using it (all I do is clear the cells before the whole thing is constructed). After that, just reference the cell you want by `grid[i][j]` and the table cell by its `id`, in the same way the attribute is set.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vut4rzod/1/). It also has an `update_board()` function for convenience.

*I would have answered sooner but I got carried away and almost implemented the entire game in jsFiddle, until I stopped myself.*